# SQL Server stores the date in the format specified in the regional setting

Tags: c#, sql-server

My computer regional setting is in the UK English format.

I am saving the date in the US format as a string from my program to SQL Sever 2008 Enterprise Edition.

But when I view the table, I see the date has been saved in the UK format . The data type of the table is nvarchar2000)

In a nutshell, I want to save the dates in the US format , irrespective of the regional settings.

Thanks
Sujay

Comment: You want to save the dates **as datetime/date-s**, you just don't know it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your saving to nvarchar then you wont be abl to control it from SQL Server,

so i bet your chance is to change the date before saving it

you can :

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");// i think en-gb is for united kingdom but not sure
fieldvalue = yourdate.ToString("d", ci);
```

then you save fieldvalue instead..

also you can use `ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");` to convert date to specific format if your not sure what culture to use, but know how you want the string to be in sql server.

Comment: I want to save the date in the US ("en-US") format irrespective of the regional setting, so if the user's regional setting has a different date format eg.UK / Denmark , I still want to save the date in the US format. ( MM/DD/YYYY)

Comment: i edited my answer to save in US format .. this will work despite of what regional settings the machine has...

Comment: System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(dtDefaultValuePicker.Value.Year, dtDefaultValuePicker.Value.Month, dtDefaultValuePicker.Value.Day);
String str = dt.ToString(ci); I am saving the string which holds the date in US format , but when I see the db table, I see the date in UK format.

Comment: you might wanna check how you save the value to the db , maybe your using something that alter the value back...